# JQuery - Append a DIV from input and then allow the user to delete/edit it

Tags: jquery

I've written some JQuery that allows me to add DIV elements/HTML to the page based upon some user input (e.g: grabbing a link and their comments on that link.)

That's working.

But I'm trying to add some code to change color when I mouse over one of the elements (the user can add more than one) and allow the user to delete it by click an 'X' or a rubbish bin icon of some sort.

For some reason (my JavaScript kung-fu is pretty weak), the `.mouseover()` function isn't working. I'm guessing it's because it can't run `.mouseover()` to it because it wasn't there when the browser first opened? (But rather added later by the other JQuery code using `append()`)

Here's the code that isn't working:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link_and_description').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('background', '#fef4a7');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css('background', '#f5f5f5');
    });
 });
```

You can see the the jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/CG4Ew/

Comment: I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CG4Ew/10/) give it a try and good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `link_and_description` elements are added dynamically you need to use event propagation to register the hover event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.link_and_description', function() {
        $(this).css('background', '#fef4a7');
    }).on('mouseleave', '.link_and_description', function(){
        $(this).css('background', '#f5f5f5');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zDyNC/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding elements dynamically the direct events attached does not have any effect as they did not exist in DOM then.  You can tacke it by using event delegation with `on()`. Bind the event to the container `#urls_go_below` for delegation to the element with the class `.link_and_description` which is getting added in the future during onclick event in your case.

Try this way.

```
 $('#urls_go_below').on({   //<-- Bind the event to the container for delegation, 
               //if '#urls_go_below' doesnot exist in DOM at the time of registring        
               //then you can use another container or worstcase document element. i.e $(document).on(...
        mouseenter: function () {
             $(this).css('background', '#fef4a7');
         },
         mouseleave: function () {
             $(this).css('background', '#f5f5f5');
         }
     },
     '.link_and_description'); // Target element which will have the event delegated.
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CbG5u/)

See [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation.

Another point is `$(function () {` is document.ready itself so you dont need to include another document ready to wrap the mouseover events.

Use mouseenter/mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout. due the below reason.

*from [docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)*

> The mouseenter event differs from mouseover in the way it handles event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseenter event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse enters the Outer element, but not the Inner element.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bind the mouseover & mouseout events when the object gets appended.

So after you append the div run something like:

```
$('#foo').bind('mouseover',function() { $(this).css('background', '#fef4a7'); });
```

Where `#foo` is your newly created element. More information on .bind() can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/bind/